# Vite - change static assets' directoy

Tags: reactjs, spring, vue.js, vite

I had build an app using **create-react-app**. And our server is set up as such that all files except `index.html` are in a folder named **static**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="./static/favicon.f99d69b1.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>App</title>
  
  <script type="module" crossorigin src="./static/index.81e5d079.js"></script>
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="./static/vendor.ba9c442b.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/index.f28d7853.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

So `JS` file's path is `./static/js/main.836d2eb0.js`.

---

And then I decided to go for Vite.

As you may know, Vite's default assets' directory is callled assets. I managed to change it to `static` by changing `build.assetsDir` to `static` in `vite.config.js`

```
  build: {
    assetsDir: "static",
    outDir: "./../backend/src/main/resources/static/app/",
  },
```

**I changed the output's directory too.**

After runing `npm run build`, all of the files are generated in the correct directory. However, CSS, JS, and other assets have  wrong path, for ex, my JS file's path is `/static/vendor.ba9c442b.js` **It lacks dot(.) before the first slush**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/static/favicon.f99d69b1.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Fiken Kundestøtte</title>
  
  <script type="module" crossorigin src="/static/index.81e5d079.js"></script>
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/static/vendor.ba9c442b.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/index.f28d7853.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**info:** It is a spring boot app.

#### So how to fix the files' path?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Configure the [`base`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#base) URL to be `./`:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  base: './', 
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-base-url?file=vite.config.js)